# Couldn’t get all links by python

Tags: python, selenium

I need the links near by src-0, src-1, src-2… src-59. How could I fix the coding ? Thanks

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get("https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/store/%E5%B1%88%E8%87%A3%E6%B0%8FWatsons:watsons")


# 商品連結

linkPath = "//ul[@class='gridList']/li/a"
product_links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(linkPath)
print(product_links)
```

Comment: do you want the link to each item ***image*** (.jpg), or ***href*** link to item page? e.g. src for `src="https://s.yimg.com/ut/api/res/1.2/Yq.qoiiWkOpluULaOmoL2A--~B/dz0xNjg7aD0xNjg7cT0xMDA7Zmk9Zml0O3NzPTEuMDthcHBpZD15dHdtYWxs/https://s.yimg.com/fy/1e0a/item/p0330221397264-item-5716xf4x0650x0650-m.jpg"` or `<a href="https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/item/p0330221397264"` ?

Comment: Link to page     <a href="https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/item/p0330221397264"

Comment: And the pages are limited within the src-0 to src-59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xpath` you are using does not highlight any elements in the DOM.

Try like below, hope these are the links you are trying to extract.

```
# Imports Required

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/store/%E5%B1%88%E8%87%A3%E6%B0%8FWatsons:watsons")

links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//section[contains(@class,'MainListing__StoreBoothWrap')]/div/div/div/ul/li/a")
print(len(links))

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

```
60
https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/item/p0330231079018
https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/item/p0330221397264
https://tw.mall.yahoo.com/item/p0330201617111
...
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your help. 
How could I find the correct Xpath?

Comment: @Dingyen - You can refer these links - [Link1](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/), [Link2](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html)